# React CTA with Modal in DropDown Pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, anti-patterns

I'm using MaterialUI's ButtonGroup as a drop down menu and having a pattern issue trying to create a series of CTAs which I can easily swap around in it; where all of the components are reusable and the choices in the dropdown is dynamic, i.e.

```
const CTAs = [
  <Foo {...foo} />, // these look like <MenuItem>{blah}</MenuItem>
  <Bar {...bar} />,
  <Baz {...baz} />,
];
return (
  <DropDown>
    {CTAs}
  </DropDown>
);
```

```
 // DropDown looks something like this
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const anchorRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <ButtonGroup variant="contained" ref={anchorRef}>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={toggleOpen}
          >
            {label}
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
        <ListWrapper
          anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
          open={open}
          setOpen={setOpen}
        > {/* Popper > Grow > Paper > ClickAwayListener > MenuList > children */}
          {children}
        </ListWrapper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
```

However, I'm running into issues when some of these CTAs need a modal confirmation as the modals break inside the dropdown; the dropdown captures text entry and closing the dropdown destroys the modal.

How do I do this?

---

What I've tried,

I've worked around this by adding a function that returns two nodes instead of just one;

```
interface CTAState {
  open: boolean;
  // and other stuff that used to be inside the CTAs
}

const GetFoo = (props): [React.ReactNode, React.ReactNode] => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<CTAState>({ open: false });
  const setOpen = (val: boolean): void => setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    open: val,
  }));

  const onSend = (): void => {
    // do cool stuff which used to be in <Foo /> click
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return [
    (<Foo {...props} onClick={() => setOpen(true)} />),
    (<Dialog open={state.open} onSend={onSend} />),
  ];
};

// .. 

const CTAs = [GetFoo(foo), GetBar(bar), GetBaz(baz)];

return (
  <DropDown>
    {CTAs.map(([button]) => button)}
  </DropDown>
  {CTAs.map(([, dialog]) => dialog)}
);
```

This seems like an anti-pattern as I'm having to use something which is not a Component with a react hook to handle state, the complexity just keeps growing and it is becoming very difficult to track what is going on within the CTA itself

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, the modal confirmation closes the dropdown, right? If so, try the following:

```
// ...
<ListWrapper
    anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
    open={open}
    setOpen={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setOpen(event)
    }}

> {/* Popper > Grow > Paper > ClickAwayListener > MenuList > children */}
    {children}
</ListWrapper>
// ...
```

Comment: When the dropdown is clicked, I don't mind if it stays open or not, but if I do this and the modal is in `{children}` then I hit back into the dropdown capturing some of my keypresses issue, and the CTAs need to be aware of the dropdown so they can close it?